# "No adapter attached; skipping layout" on a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

```
public class WorkFragment extends Fragment {

List<CardViewItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("FRAGMENT", "Work Fragment started");

    TypedArray icons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.project_icons);
    TypedArray names = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.project_names);
    TypedArray descs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.project_descs);
    for (int i=0;i<icons.length();i++){
        items.add(new CardViewItem(icons.getDrawable(i),
                names.getString(i),
                descs.getString(i)));
    }
    icons.recycle();
    names.recycle();
    descs.recycle();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("FRAGMENT", "Work Fragment onCreateView");
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_work, container, false);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new ItemAdapter(items));
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_work, container, false);
}
}
```

Gives me

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

I have tried out all the solutions I had found (setting an empty adapter, moving the code elswhere, using a seperate thread) but to no avail. This should work on a normal activity so I guess maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is mostly this line

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_work, container, false);
```

you should have

`return rootView`

With the first return you are inflating a new totally different view hierarchy, starting from  `fragment_work.xml`, from the one which has an the `RecyclerView` correctly set up.

Comment: Worst bugs are hidden in plain sight. Thanks!